# Cake PHP 2.x save form does nothing

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp

I am new to cakePhP and I need your help.

I am trying to make a calendar that manages events. So I chose the fullcalendar jQuery plugin to do so. Then, I followed this tutorial to integrate the calendar in my project in order to store events in my database :

[link to the tutorial](http://duckranger.com/2010/03/fullcalendar-and-cakephp-part-3-adding-events/)

I know it deals with an older version of cakePHP, but I kept going on, until the part I shared. My calendar displays correctly events stored in my database. But I can't add events,
and here is the real problem. 
I use a save form in a add.ctp view like this :`

```
<?php


    echo $this->Form->create("Event",array('action'=>'add'));   
    echo $this->Form->input('title' , array('label' => 'Nom de l\'absence'));
    echo '<br/> Quand : ' . $displayTime;
    echo $this->Form->input('allday', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$event['Event']['allday']));
    echo $this->Form->input('start', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$event['Event']['start']));
    echo $this->Form->input('end', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$event['Event']['end']));

    echo  $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'Save' ,'name' => 'save'));

?>
<input type="button" value="Retour" onclick="back();">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function back() {
        window.location.href ="/calendars/display";
    }
</script>
```

`

When I click on a day on my calendar it launches the form correctly, but when I click on Save, nothing happens.

This is how my table is made :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `allday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `editable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is 'add' in the controller :

```
function add($allday=null,$day=null,$month=null,$year=null,$hour=null,$min=null) {
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    //Create and save the new event in the table.
    $this->Event->create();
    $this->data['Event']['editable']='1';

    if($this->Event->save($data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash('GG');
    }
    else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('ERROR');
    }
}else{
    //Set default duration: 1hr and format to a leading zero.
    $hourPlus=intval($hour)+1;
    if (strlen($hourPlus)==1) {
        $hourPlus = '0'.$hourPlus;
    }

    //Create a time string to display in view. 
    if ($allday=='true') {
        $event['Event']['allday'] = 1;
        $displayTime = 'All day event: ('
            . date('D',strtotime($day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year)).' '.
            $day.' / '. date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10)).')';
    } else {
        $event['Event']['allday'] = 0;
        $displayTime = date('D',strtotime($day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year)).' '
            .$day.' / '.date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10)).
            ', '.$hour.' : '.$min.' &mdash; '.$hourPlus.' : '.$min;
    }
    $this->set("displayTime",$displayTime);

    //Populate the event fields for the add form
    $event['Event']['title'] = 'Nom de l\'événement';
    $event['Event']['start'] = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$hour.':'.$min.':00';
    $event['Event']['end'] = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$hourPlus.':'.$min.':00';
    $this->set('event',$event);

    $this->layout="ajax";
}
```

It enters in my first else block and shows me then "ERROR".
I used debugger but nothing seems anormal. validationErrors() array is empty, 
the last query done is one acos, aros and permissions, and the array contents the good data, ready to store, but doesn't want to save it...

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question : on the line

if($this->Event->save($data)){

just replace $data with $this->data

took me several days to get out of the shame